# Measuring percentage of visitors connecting over https

Tags: google-analytics, https

Does Google Analytics expose information about the connection protocol used by site visitors? I don't see any option in the customization section... is this something I'd have to use a custom variable to capture?

Comment: Which version? Universal Analytics (beta) or Google Analytics (classic)? If you don't know, just paste your tracking code here (omit UA-XXXXXX code)

Comment: classic. ga.js.

Comment: This is a distinct question. I'm not interested in joining the records across http and https, but rather segmenting traffic based on the protocol.